# MYSQL Search for empty fields in table

Tags: mysql

I'm search through multiple tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cv.id, cv.tJobTitle, cv.tJobTitleAlt, cv.rEmployer, employee.firstName, employee.surname, cv.recentJobTitle, match ( cv.title, cv.recentJobTitle, cv.targetJobTitle, cv.targetJobTitleAlt ) AGAINST ('Desktop' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 

FROM cv AS cv, employee AS employee, country AS country 

WHERE cv.showTo=1 AND cv.status=1 AND cv.employeeIDFK = employee.id AND cv.countryISO2FK='GB' 
AND cv.countryISO2FK=country.iso2 
AND match ( cv.title, cv.recentJobTitle, cv.targetJobTitle, cv.targetJobTitleAlt ) AGAINST ('Desktop' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) 
AND cv.salaryType='1' AND cv.salaryMax <=23088 OR cv.salaryMin is NUll 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

I have a price values which I am search in my database but I also have a tick box to say if the price has not be set show that record.

So If the price field is empty then still show in result.

I have try the above but its giving me more the 100 records where my table only has 2 records.

Comment: 1st of all, you are not defining a join between t1 and t2 so you will get a Cartesian product, which you don't want, i assume.  secondly, are you sure you want 0-length non-null values ('') or null?  i would guess you would want to search for null

Answer (score 1):

Assuming country.iso2  is a unique field, I'm guessing that you multiple cv's per employee or vice-versa.

NOTE: It's good advice to avoid using the comman notation for INNER JOINs.   Also, this will only work where your field3 is really empty and not NULL.

Comment: I have put AND filed3 = '' but its giving me more then 100 records